# For IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, is the mantissa in [0.5, 1) or in [1, 2)?

Tags: math, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I was looking at several textbooks, including *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau, and in the section on floating point arithmetic, they seem to say that in IEEE-754, normalized floating point numbers take the form `.1.... X 2^e`. That is, the mantissa is assumed to be between 0.5 and 1.

However, in this [popular online floating point calculator](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), it is explained that normalized floating point numbers have a mantissa between 1 and 2.

Could someone please tell me which is the correct way?

Comment: It is actually explained already on the page you linked - *An invisible leading bit (i.e. it is not actually stored) with value 1.0 is placed in front, then bit 23 has a value of 1/2, bit 22 has value 1/4 etc. As a result, the mantissa has a value between 1.0 and 2.*

Comment: @wim Yes that's exactly the sentence I was looking at. But in my textbooks (including some very popular ones like the one by Trefethen) the mantissa is between 0.5 and 1. That is, the "invisible 1" is assumed to be immediately to the right of the decimal point, not to the left.

Comment: @wim: That page is wrong. First, the stored bits are not the significand. They are an encoding of the significand. The “value” of those bits is not the value of the significand. Second, bits stored in the low 23 bits are merely the primary encoding of the significand. The page is wrong to say the leading bit is not stored. It is in fact encoded via the exponent field, which is stored in the next 8 bits. If those bits, interpreted as a binary numeral, are 1-254, the leading bit of the significand is 1. If they are 0, the leading bit of the significand is 0.

Comment: user56202, "is the mantissa in [0.5, 1) or in [1, 2)" --> Yes.  Your choice.

Comment: Which part specifically wrong? It does go on to cover the case where the significand is in [0,1) and the leading bit is not used.

Comment: @wim: The parts I noted were wrong are wrong. It is wrong to say the significand is stored in the low 23 bits. Only part of the significand is stored in the low 23 bits. It is wrong to say the leading bit is not stored. If it were not stored, we could not know what it is. It is stored, just in an encoded way. E.g., the IEEE 754-2008 standard does not say the leading bit is not stored; it says it “is implicitly encoded in the biased exponent *E*” (clause 3.4, paragraph 2).

Comment: I have no dog in the race, but the page is describing those things in a different way. You are saying the same things just using different language.  

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All ways are correct. The following sets are identical:

- { (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•*f*•2<sup>*e*</sup> | *s* ∈ {0, 1}, *f* is the value of a 24-bit binary numeral with a radix point after the first digit, and *e* is an integer such that −126 ≤ *e* ≤ 127 }.
- { (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•*f*•2<sup>*e*</sup> | *s* ∈ {0, 1}, *f* is the value of a 24-bit binary numeral with a radix point before the first digit, and *e* is an integer such that −125 ≤ *e* ≤ 128 }.
- { (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•*f*•2<sup>*e*</sup> | *s* ∈ {0, 1}, *f* is the value of a 24-bit binary numeral with a radix point after the last digit, and *e* is an integer such that −149 ≤ *e* ≤ 104 }.
- { *f*•2<sup>*e*</sup> | *f* is an integer such that |*f*| < 2<sup>24</sup>, and *e* is an integer such that −149 ≤ *e* ≤ 104 }.

In other words, we may put the radix point anywhere in the significand we want, simply by adjusting the range of the exponent to compensate. Which form to use may be chosen for convenience or preference.

The third form scales the significand so it is an integer, and the fourth form incorporates the sign into the significand. This form is convenient for using number theory to analyze floating-point behavior.

IEEE 754 mostly uses the first form. It refers to this as “a scientific form,” reflecting the fact that, in scientific notation, we commonly write numbers with a radix point just after the first digit, as in “The mass of the Earth is about 5.9722•10<sup>24</sup> kg.” In clause 3.3, IEEE 754-2008 mentions “It is also convenient for some purposes to view the significand as an integer; in which case the finite floating-point numbers are described thus:”, followed by text equivalent to the third form above except that it is generalized (the base and other parameters are arbitrary values for any floating-point format rather than the constants I used above specifically for the binary32 format).

The C standard describes numbers in the second form (for any base, not necessarily baes two), with the radix point before the first digit, and the exponent provided by its `frexp` function matches this scale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In all the sets, you are letting `e` range over 254 values; but 8 bits have 256 different configurations. Could you please explain the discrepancy?

Comment: @user56202: When the stored exponent field is 255, the floating-point datum is infinity or NaN. For the stored exponent field values 0 and 1, the represented exponent is the same (−126 in the first form above), but the leading bit of the significand is 0 when the exponent field is 0. So there are only 254 exponent values encoded by the exponent field.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see. Thank you again! After confusing myself with numerous sources, it is incredibly refreshing to have such clear information.